# History state pushing and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm having a problem with tracking my website via `history.state/pushing`. I have this Google Analytics code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Now I have the event listener to check when `history.pushState` occours:

```
<script>
(function(history){
    var pushState = history.pushState;
    history.pushState = function(state) {
        if (typeof history.onpushstate == "function") {
            history.onpushstate({state: state});
        }
        // ... whatever else you want to do
        // maybe call onhashchange e.handler
        return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
    }
})(window.history);

function __inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

window.onpopstate = history.onpushstate = function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var path = document.location.pathname;

        ga('set', path);
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    }, 650);
}
</script>
```

Tracks good and it sends the appopriate URL's where it should, but the Chrome extension **Tag Assistant (by Google)** reports me:

> Same web property ID is tracked twice.

And the second instance of my Google Analytics tracking code appears in the list, in the **Tag Assistant**.

What's wrong with my implementation and/or approach?

---

**Edit:**

I have like four URL's:

```
/home
/home/personal-info
/home/employment-info
/home/privacy-settings
/home/documents
```

And I don't want `/home` tracked.

Comment: Just curious how you believe the history.pushState implementation is causing the TA error message. They may be unrelated.

Comment: What else could have cause it?

Comment: Do you have iframes on your site that could be running the same GA code? It's harder to tell without actually seeing the site.

Comment: No. No iframes whatsoever. This is the page: https://goo.gl/Y6O4Li

Comment: I'm not seeing any duplicate tracking codes, and my TA shows green and happy, and I only see one pageview on page load, so looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed it who @antishok suggested.

Comment: Well, actually, it doesn't work... can you check it again?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. I'm confused now. What doesn't work? And do you still think it's a history pushState issue? You had the issue of the page path not being set correctly. That should be corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag Assistant Recordings reports a warning that a page is tracked twice if the page sends more than one pageview hit in a short time period.

(Tag Assistant Recordings currently does not consider the parameters of the pageview, and that's something that probably should change in Tag Assistant)

In this case you have a pageview hit in the initialization of the page, and one in the event handler.

Comment: Can you give me an example of correct implementation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the path correctly.
Should be `ga('set', 'page', path)` or you can just do `ga('send', 'pageview', path)`

Comment: And how do I send a `pageview`?